# apt update gives errors

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, lubuntu

When I run the command `sudo apt update`, I get the following errors:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8873E7BF70F1BBEA

W: Failed to fetch http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_6.0/./Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 154.53.224.162 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and use `lubuntu-desktop`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have some crap in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Some opensuse and debian repos.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/V4WEQUaW) is what is in my sources file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Taking a look around

It doesn't look like your [sources.list](http://pastebin.com/raw/V4WEQUaW) contains `http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_6.0/./Packages`.

You will need to check the files within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and find the problematic file containing this repo.  After you delete the file, or comment out the line, try `sudo apt-get update` to see if you've fixed the problem.

#### Note

If you wish to use mega.nz as a repository for `MEGAsync`, you will need to find the updated/correct URL, as well as determine and import the signer's public key (`apt-key`).  Please read up on `apt` and how it uses public/private keys before importing keys without understanding the consequences.

Comment: Deleting the file worked. How to I fix/delete the `W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8873E7BF70F1BBEA
`  error?

Comment: Using `apt-key`, as the **Note** portion says.  Also, Google: *8873E7BF70F1BBEA* .